# PIC18F45K80 SPI communication with QT1481

Tags: pic, spi

I have MPLAB X installed and I am trying to programme code that sends the command 0x0F from PIC18F45K80 (RX not connected. Could I be possible to send command to MOSI and then get a response to MISO) to QT1481 using C language. The internal clock should be 1MHz. The output should send 0x0F and the QT1481 should send back 0xF0 back to the PIC18F45K80. I am using docklight (serial terminal software) to see if I can receive a response.

Introduction
The QT1481 uses either SPI or UART communications modes; it cannot use both at the same time. The QT1481
responds on whichever interface it receives a command. The QT1481 also includes a Debug output interface, which
can be used to monitor many operating variables during product development.
The host device always initiates communications sequences; the QT1481 is incapable of chattering data back to the
host. This is intentional for FMEA and IEC/EN60730 purposes so that the host always has total control over the
communications with the QT1481.

 In SPI mode the QT1481 is a slave, so that even return data following a command is controlled by the host.

 In UART mode, the QT1481 still only responds to the host after a command, but the responses are not controlled by the host.

A command from the host always ends in a response of some kind from the QT1481. Some transmission types from
the host or the QT1481 employ a CRC check byte to provide for robust communications.
A DRDY line that handshakes transmissions is provided. This is needed by the host from the QT1481 to ensure that
transmissions are not sent when the QT1481 is busy or has not yet processed a prior command. In UART mode this
line is bidirectional, and the QT1481 can use it to suspend transmissions back to the host if the host is busy.
If the host does not observe the correct DRDY timing, random communication errors may result.
Initiating or Resetting Communications:
After a reset, or should communications be lost due to noise or out-of-sequence reception, the host should
repeatedly wait for a period not less than the QT1481 communications time-out (110 ms ±5 ms), and send a
0x0F (return last command) command until the complement of 0x0F, which is 0xF0, is received. Then, the
host can resume normal run mode communications from a clean start.

```
  /*
     * File:   main.c
     * Author: Mateusz
     *
     * Created on 18 October 2018, 11:59
    */


    #include <xc.h>
    #include <PIC18F45K80.h>
    #include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define SPI_CLK TRISCbits.TRISC3
    #define SPI_SDI TRISCbits.TRISC4
    #define SPI_SDO TRISCbits.TRISC5
    #define SPI_SS  TRISDbits.TRISD4

    unsigned char SPI_Recv[256];

    //Declaration Methods for EUSART!

    void WriteChar (unsigned char _data);
    void WriteText (unsigned char *text); 
    void Delay ();
    void Configuration_EUSART();
    void GetChar (); 

    //****************** Declaration SPI MASTER COnfiguration 
    *******************************

    void SPI_Init();
    void SPI_Write(unsigned char data);
    void SPI_Read();

    void main(void)
    {
        Configuration_EUSART();
        SPI_Init();
        while (1)
        {   
            WriteText("0x0F");
            SPI_Read();
            for (int x=0; x<=500;x++)
            {
                __delay_ms(100);
            }
        } 
    }

    void WriteChar(unsigned char _data)//Writing a character
    {
        if (PIR1bits.TXIF == 1)// if TXIF = 1 The EUSART Transmit Buffer 
       TXREG is empty and its ready to send the next data
        {
            while(!TXSTAbits.TRMT);
            TXREG = _data;
        }
    }   

    void WriteText (unsigned char *text) //Writing Text
    {
        for(int i=0; text[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            WriteChar(text[i]);
        }
    }

    void Configuration_EUSART()
    {

        //--------------------------------------------PIC18F13K50 Configuration USART------------------------------------------------//

        // Configuration Signal Tx & Rx
        BAUDCON1bits.CKTXP = 0;// 0 = NO - invert the polarity data and prevent the incorrect function in the PIC using the UART in the Transmision Data TX  
        BAUDCON1bits.DTRXP = 0;// 0 = NO - invert the polarity data and prevent the incorrect function in the PIC using the UART in the Receive Data RX
        // Oscillator Configuration
        //OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b110; // internal Oscillator Selection IRCF <2:0> 8 Mhz
        //OSCCONbits.SCS = 0b00; // 0b00 = Prevent the modification and select de Oscillator FOSC in configuration bits
        //Configuration PIN TX and RX
        //ANSELHbits.ANS11 = 0; //Digital input buffer  RB5 (Rx) is enabled
        //ANSELHbits.ANS10 = 0; //Digital Output buffer  RB4 (SDA) is enabled
        TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1; // RB5 (Rx) Input Mode
        TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 1; // RB7 (Tx) Input Mode, SPEN will reconfigured the pin RB7 as Output when is required

        //-------Baud Rate --------
        // BAUDCONbits.BRG16 = 1; //Times of 16 bits
        // TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1; // if BRHG is clear is (low) and if is set is (High) 
        // SPBRG = 25; // This Decimal Number (25) represent the Baud rate 115200 at 12 Mhz (see the datasheet)

        //Serial Port Configuration
        TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // Async Mode
        TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1; // Enable Transmission
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // Enable reception bit Rx
        RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // Enable Serial Port
   }

// -------------------------------------- SPI CONFIG --------------------------------------------//
void SPI_Init(){
    //set tris bits for serial port pins
    SPI_CLK = 0; //output
    SPI_SDI = 1; //input
    SPI_SDO = 0; //output
    SPI_SS = 0; //output

    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; // Clear interrupt flag
    PIE1bits.SSPIE = 0; // Disable MSSP interrupt
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 0; // Disable perriferal interrupts


    SSPSTATbits.SMP = 0; //input samled at middle of interval
    SSPSTATbits.CKE = 0; //Data transmitted from low to high clock

    //Enable SSP, Master mode, clock Fosc/4
    SSPCON1 |= 0b00100000;

}

void SPI_Write(unsigned char data){
    unsigned char TempVar;
    TempVar = SSPBUF; // Clears BF
    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; // Clear interrupt flag
    SSPBUF = data; // write byte to SSPBUF register
    while(!PIR1bits.SSPIF) {}; // wait until bus cycle complete
        //return ( 0 ); // if WCOL bit is not set return non-negative#
}

void SPI_Read()
{
     WriteText(" Here2");
     PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; // Clear interrupt flag

     for (int i=0; i<=256;i++)
     {   
         WriteText(" Here3");
         SPI_Recv[i] = SSPBUF; // Save the data in SSPBUFF
         WriteText(" Here4");
         while(!PIR1bits.SSPIF) {}; // wait until bus cycle complete
         WriteText(" Here5");

     }


     WriteText(" Here6");
     WriteText(SPI_Recv);
     WriteText(" Here7");

}
```

Comment: What have you attempted this far? Unfortunately we can't help if we can't see the code you've written and need help with.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: Hi sorry I am trying to copy the code but I cannot upload to this post. This is my first post so sorry.